# Pasar datos de un datagridview a otro en otro formulario

Tags: c#

Tengo el formulario **Citas** en el cual esta el `datagridview(dgvprocesos)` y el formulario **Facturas** en el cual esta el `datagrid(dgvfacturas)` quiero saber como envió toda la información del `dgvprocesos` al `dgvfacturas` al presionar un botón. La información que esta en el `dgvprocesos` es introducida de forma manual, no se alimenta de ningún origen de datos. intente con esto que encontré aquí pero me da error en el `add`:

```
CrearFactura cf = new CrearFactura();


            List<DataGridViewRow> items = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

            foreach (var row in dgvprocesos.Rows)
            {
                items.Add(row);
            }

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                cf.dgvfactura.Rows.Add(new string[] {
            Convert.ToString(item.Cells[0].Value),
            Convert.ToString(item.Cells[1].Value),
            Convert.ToString(item.Cells[2].Value)
        });

                dgvprocesos.Rows.Remove(item);
            }
            cf.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a poner un ejemplo con datos más simples y nombres simplificados:

Tu caso sería el siguiente: Tengo un formulario llamado `Form1`, en el que tengo una lista, en este caso, `ListaNotas`.
Cuando pulso un botón en `Form1` quiero que esa lista se envíe a `Form2`.

Por tanto, tal y como lo tienes tú

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 <int> ListaNotas = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 Form2 form2 = new Form2();
 form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Pero de esta forma, perderemos por completo en Form2 nuestra lista. Por tanto lo que haremos es en el constructor de Form2, añadir la lista.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 <int> ListaNotas = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 Form2 form2 = new Form2(ListaNotas);
 form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Y para que no tengamos errores y poder manejarlos, nos movemos a `Form2.cs` y en el constructor lo cambiamos a :

```
public Form2(List<int> lista)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

En este caso ya podemos trabajar con nuestra lista. Lo que quieras hacer en ese punto ya es de tu elección. Puedes crear un atributo de la clase y asignarselo, de esta forma podrás usar tu lista en cualquier parte de la clase.